# Blending Mode in GLB model has partly geometries [three.js] [aframe] [8thwall-xr]

Tags: three.js, aframe, 8thwall-xr

e.g. a box should be Blending Mode,
but when it run perfectly in aframe debug inspector,
but it does not work in the 8thwall WebAR Camera,
since the "camera" plane also Addiative become White within once second.

Can this be solve?

it eventually turn out all Blank White,

i was using "modify-material" code from 8thwall example

```
<a-scene
    xrweb="disableWorldTracking: true"
    xrextras-almost-there
    xrextras-loading
    xrextras-runtime-error>

AFRAME.registerComponent('modify-materials', {
    init: function() {

...

if (node.name.indexOf('p_TBSPart') !== -1) {

node.material.transparent = true;
//node.material.depthWrite: false;
node.material.blending = THREE.AdditiveBlending;
console.log("blend:" + node.material.blending+";<br/>");
} else {
node.material.transparent = false;
node.material.blending = THREE.NormalBlending;
console.log("b_:" + node.material.blending+";<br/>");
}

..

</a-scene>
```

Thank you

--
TBSFred

Comment: finally, i find out when i dont include this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-render-order-component@1.1.0/dist/aframe-render-order-component.min.js">
</script>
```

the Blend mode is ok,
The render-Order Component is conflict with the AddictiveBlending
now finding workaround.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-render-order-component

oh, after i switch off  nonrecursive , it correct!? 

Non-Recursive
The component will apply render order recursively by default. To define to be not recursive, set the nonrecursive ID:

<a-entity render-order__nonrecursive="hud"></a-entity>